# Position Google Maps InfoWindow slightly above marker

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Can Anyone provide any insight on how to position the infoMarker from Google Maps slightly above my marker at all times. The code below is hacky and does not work that well. Thanks!

```
                <InfoWindow
                  onCloseClick={() => setActive(null)}
                  position={{ lat: parseFloat(active.location.latitude) + 0.02, lng: parseFloat(active.location.longitude) }}>
                  <div className='ServiceDiscoveryPage__info-marker'>
                    <img src={active.imgBg} alt={active.imgBg} />
                    <img src={active.img} alt='activity' />
                    <h3>{active.address1}</h3>
                    <p>{active.summary} </p>
                  </div>
                </InfoWindow>
```

**solution**:

```
            <InfoWindow
              onCloseClick={() => setActive(null)}
              position={{ lat: parseFloat(active.latitude), lng: parseFloat(active.longitude) }}
              options={{
                pixelOffset: new window.google.maps.Size(0, -25)
              }}
```

Comment: What google maps react library are you using? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible sample](http://sscce.org/) of your code? You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the pixelOffset of the Info Window? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions